# Angular Material Expansion Panel Wrapper issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created my own version of the Angular Material Expansion Panel components, each wrapping the appropriate Material component (e.g. expansion panel header etc.)

example at 
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-issue-repro2-4wcj9i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

In my wrapped version, nothing gets displayed.

I'm interested both in solving the immediate issue (ie I want my own wrapped version) and understanding why this doesn't work.)

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

add this line in 
styles.css file

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

and add the below line in pollyfills.ts;

```
import 'hammerjs';
```

Comment: Sorry but that has nothing to do with the issue - I did it just to be sure, but obviously it has no effect. If you look at the Blitz, you will see that the native Material expansion panel works already - so making the changes you suggest are unnecessary in this instance.
Thanks for taking a look, though.